# Optimize label position in Graphviz

Tags: graphviz, dot

The following dotfile is creating a massive output :

```
digraph G {
    "Bob"->"A" [label=" A very long label"]
    "Bob"->"B" [label=" A very long label"]
    "Bob"->"C" [label=" A very long label"]
    "Bob"->"D" [label=" A very long label"]
    "Bob"->"E" [label=" A very long label"]
    "Bob"->"F" [label=" A very long label"]
    "Bob"->"G" [label=" A very long label"]
}
```

Outputs something like this :
[image: Huge graph]

Is there a way to change the label positions to reduce the graph size ?

Answer (score 9):

Labels can be positioned with [`lp`](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:lp). You could change the [`labelangle`](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:labelangle). There are also [`headlabel`](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:headlabel) and [`taillabel`](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:taillabel) labels.
Search for 'label' in the [documentation](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:lp).

Answer (score 7):

Very simple \n solution

```
digraph G {
    "Bob"->"A" [label=" A very\nlong\nlabel"]
    "Bob"->"B" [label=" A very\nlong\nlabel"]
    "Bob"->"C" [label=" A very\nlong\nlabel"]
    "Bob"->"D" [label=" A very\nlong\nlabel"]
    "Bob"->"E" [label=" A very\nlong\nlabel"]
    "Bob"->"F" [label=" A very\nlong\nlabel"]
    "Bob"->"G" [label=" A very\nlong\nlabel"]
}
```